# Why is the simplest user AJAX registration not working in WordPress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm testing the elementary AJAX registration of a new user. For this I use a really simple code.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('#client-registration button').on('click',function(e){
    let email = jQuery('#client-registration').find('input[name=client_mail]').val();
    let username = jQuery('#client-registration').find('input[name=client_name]').val();
    let password = jQuery('#client-registration').find('input[name=client_password]').val();
    data = {
        'action': 'ajax_add_client',
        'username': username,
        'email': email,
        'password': password
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = "/";
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**And here is PHP part:**

```
function ajax_add_client()
{
   $user = array();
   $user['user_login'] = sanitize_user( $_POST[ 'username' ] );
   $user['user_email'] = sanitize_email( $_POST[ 'email' ] );
   $user[ 'user_pass' ] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'password' ] );
   $user_register = wp_insert_user($user);
}
```

The request is sent, the function seems to work, but the user is not added. Debag log is also empty. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked the result of `wp_insert_user`? If the user is not created it will most likely return a WP_Error object with an error message that will point you towards the reason for the failing creation. Please provide the result of `wp_insert_user`

Comment: @mynd Hi! no, I didn't check the result, but it's seem I understand the problem. The username was entered not in Latin but in Cyrillic. And because of this, there was a mistake. I will double-check this consideration now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `wp_ajax` or `wp_ajax_nopriv` action hooks to use WordPress ajax. check the below code.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_add_client', 'ajax_add_client' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_add_client', 'ajax_add_client' );
function ajax_add_client(){
   $user = array();
   $user['user_login'] = sanitize_user( $_POST[ 'username' ] );
   $user['user_email'] = sanitize_email( $_POST[ 'email' ] );
   $user['user_pass']  = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'password' ] );
   $user_register = wp_insert_user($user);
}
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [AJAX_in_Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)